# How can I add an iframe to a model-driven app main form?

Tags: iframe, dynamics-crm, powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

I'm a .Net Developer I am not having any experience on model-driven app. How can I add an iframe to a model-driven app main form?

Curently I am using External website component and added a hardcoded SiteURL into this compontent. I would like to display an image from sharepoint into this Iframe for the item which we are selecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/use-iframe-and-web-resource-controls-on-a-form
I believe that url will dynamically change depending on the contextual record so you will have to include JS to build that url and populate it onload of the record's form.